# How to simulate network latency/ artificially add latency to a network?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, networking, latency

I need to make a Windows program using .NET, C, C# that adds latency to data moving through that computer on a network. Basically, if I have a room full of computers, I want to this program to turn a computer into a node that delays the information that moves through it as if that info is going from one computer to another 500 miles away. This is to test programs in a lab as if they are being used over the internet. The program has to handle udp, tcp, ipv4, ipv6, and pim multicast connections.

I've been digging through the .NET [System.Net API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) trying to figure out which API tools would be helpful, but I'm not really sure where to begin. Do I need to to make a client program and a server program and use System.Net.Sockets for tcp and udp connections and ip endpoints for ipv4 and ipv6?

If possible, I'd like to make one program that you run on one computer that adds latency to everything running through it. Is this possible/feasible?

I wish I had more to present to get more specific answers, but I'm just not sure where to begin on this one.

Comment: 500 miles away... so... 2ms delay? :)

Comment: Sure, or thousands of miles, or however great a distance that would cause up to 1000ms delay.

Comment: 1000ms - nowhere on earth

Comment: Satellites are pretty far.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of products that already do this, out there:that sit in the stack and allow you to tweaks line speeds, latency, packet Loss, duplication of packets and so on.

[The dummynet project](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/)

[SoftPerfect Connection Emulator](http://www.softperfect.com/products/connectionemulator/)

Comment: I'm looking through the dummynet project to see how it works. I need to make my own program that is similar to dummynet, but with only latency functionality. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Could you explain to me what stack you're referring to? Is it a network stack or have something to do with the windows network layer?

Also, how would I access the stack with C or C# (what libraries/classes/methods would help me do this)?

Any and all information you mind sharing is much appreciated.

Comment: The ISO Model Layers 3-5 are typically the ones you can hook into. Typically you access these API's through device drivers or SDK's if you really want to get at all the finer details.